# HBase connection pooling for very frequent scanning of row

Tags: java, hbase

I have to scan the table for row very frequent(~million times) in an hour. I have the information about rowid(which is a byte array). I am creating rowid for creating startrow and endrow which are essentially the same in my case.

```
     public String someMethod(byte[] rowid){
            if (aTable == null) {
                  aTable = new HTable(Config.getHadoopConfig(),
                  Config.getATable());     
            }
            byte[] endRow = new byte[rowId.length];
            endrow = System.copyArray(rowId, 0, endRow, 0, rowId.length)
            Scan scan = new Scan(rowId , endRow)
            //scanner implementation and iteration over the result
            (ResultScanner result = aTable.getScanner(scan);) {
                   for (Result item : result) {

                   }
            }
     }
```

I am wondering whether I can implement some connection pooling for improving the performance. IS there any pooling mechanism available in HBase Java API. I am using 0.96.x version of HBase. Also, is there any configuration setting which can improve the performance. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken From [http://hbase.apache.org/book.html](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#client.connections)

> **Connection Pooling**
>
> For applications which require high-end multithreaded access (e.g.,
>   web-servers or application servers that may serve many application
>   threads in a single JVM), you can pre-create an HConnection, as shown
>   in the following example:
>
> Example 9.1. Pre-Creating a HConnection

```
// Create a connection to the cluster.
HConnection connection = HConnectionManager.createConnection(Configuration);
HTableInterface table = connection.getTable("myTable");
// use table as needed, the table returned is lightweight
table.close();
// use the connection for other access to the cluster
connection.close();
```

Comment: This is deprecated now. Please refer to Puneet's answer

Answer (score 12):

Connection pooling API has been changed since version 1.0.

New API code for reference of readers:

```
// Create a connection to the cluster.
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
try (Connection connection = 
  ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
  Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tablename))) {
// use table as needed, the table returned is lightweight
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now. The `HConnection` interface has been deprecated a long time ago

Comment: HBase Book : http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#client.connection.pooling

Comment: How is this connection pooling? The code in ConnectionFactory.createConnection creates a new connection every time! In a Connection pool we pre-create N no. of connections & the pool grows or shrinks as required. This code doesn't do that, right?

Answer (score 2):

Connection is thread safe, and very heavy-weight(this includes the zookeeper and socket connections etc), Hence it should be created only once per application and shared across threads.
Table is light weight and but NOT thread-safe.Only one thread can use a table instance and hence it is better to use `HBaseconfiguration` instance when using Table instances. 
Using HBaseConfiguration, will ensure the sharing of the Zookeeper and socket instances to the Region servers as well.

Sample Code:

```
Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.addResource("hbase-site.xml");
try{
   Connection connection = 
   ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
   Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf("tableName"));
   Get getVal = new Get(Bytes.toBytes("rowkey"));
   Result result = table.get(getVal);
   byte [] value = 
   result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"),Bytes.toBytes("dataCol"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recomend reuse the connection instance.

```
// Create a connection to the cluster.
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);

try (Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tablename))) {
// use table as needed, the table returned is lightweight
}
```

As quite big (by default) thread pool executor for batch processing is initialized for each connection instance.

```
HConnectionImplementation implements ClusterConnection, Closeable {
...
private ExecutorService getBatchPool() {
  if (batchPool == null) {
    synchronized (this) {
      if (batchPool == null) {
        this.batchPool = getThreadPool(conf.getInt("hbase.hconnection.threads.max", 256),
            conf.getInt("hbase.hconnection.threads.core", 256), "-shared-", null);
        this.cleanupPool = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return this.batchPool;
}
```