# Spring HbaseTemplate keeping connection alive

Tags: java, spring, hbase, spring-data-hadoop

I managed to integrate `Hbase` into a `Spring` app using `HbaseTemplate`:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class ItemRepositoryImpl implements ItemRepository {

    @Autowired
    private HbaseTemplate hbaseTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<Item> findAll() {
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.addColumn(CF, CQ);
        hbaseTemplate.find("TABLE_NAME", scan, (result, rowNum) -> {
            return new Item(...)
        });
    }
}
```

However, the connection to Hbase is opened every time I run `findAll()` (and closed just after). I read somewhere that the way to keep the connection alive is to use `Connection` and `Table` for calls to Hbase. The problem is that `HbaseTemplate` uses `HConnection` and `HTableInterface`.

How can I keep my connection alive using `HbaseTemplate`? Initiating a new connection is very time-consuming and I'd like to do it only once. Alternatively is there any other way to connect to Hbase from a `Spring` app?

I'm using:

```
org.springframework.data:spring-data-hadoop:2.5.0.RELEASE
org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:1.1.2
```

Comment: Doesn't Hbase have connection pooling?

Comment: Yes, I can do it using a standalone `hbase-client`, like proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835307/hbase-connection-pooling-for-very-frequent-scanning-of-row). I just don't know how to do it using `Spring` data tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions to this problem:

**Custom HbaseTemplate which extends `HbaseAccessor` and implements `HbaseOperations`**

The best way seems to be to create a custom class which extends `HbaseAccessor` and implements `HbaseOperations` in the similar way as the original `HbaseTemplate` does, but using the newer API (ie. `Table` instead of `HTableInterface` etc.)

One of the examples how it's implemented can be found in the [easyhbase](https://github.com/fchenxi/easyhbase/tree/master/easyhbase-client/src/main/java/cn/easyhbase/client/hbase) project.

**Injecting `Connection` instead of `HbaseTemplate`**

The other solution is to inject `Connection` to the repository and do all the heavy lifting there:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;
import java.stream.Collectors;
import java.stream.StreamSupport;

@Component
public class ItemRepositoryImpl implements ItemRepository {

    @Autowired
    private Connection connection;

    @Override
    public List<Item> findAll() throws IOException {
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.addColumn(CF, CQ);
        try (Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(TABLE_NAME))) {
            return StreamSupport
                .stream(table.getScanner(scan).spliterator, false)
                .map(...)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
}
```

The `Connection` @Bean can be configured like that:

```
@Configuration
public class HbaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Connection() throws IOException {
        org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        // configuration setup
        return ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
    }

}
```